# Existence of a set of the true sentences consistent?

Tags: set-theory

In order to make my question precise:

Let $L$ be the language of first-order logic consisting exactly of a binary predicate symbol $\in$ and a constant symbol $t$. For every $\{\in\}$-formula $\varphi$ let $g(\varphi)$ denote the Gödel-number of $\varphi$.

Assume ZFC is consistent. Is the theory

$T\;:=\;\operatorname{ZFC}\cup\{\varphi\leftrightarrow( g(\varphi)\in t)\;|\;\varphi\text{ is an } \{\in\}-\text{sentence}\}$

consistent, too?

Comment: By $\{\epsilon\}$-formula, do you mean a formula that does not contain $t$?

Comment: Yes, you are right.